# How to automate the opening of cheese in ubuntu via python?

Tags: 16.04, python, webcam, cheese

So long story short, I need to open camera in python, click a picture, save it somewhere predefined and then feed it to my trained neural network and get some response.

I saw cheese and it looks cool and already has all the GUI elements that I need. So I was wondering whether I can first preview the feed to the user using cheese, then after a timer, click the picture of the user.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It could very well be me, but I don't really get the picture. Too many unclear events in the not-so-clear timeline.

Comment: I'll clarify some more. What I need is basically a preview of my webcam feed for a while say 5 seconds, after that it click a picture of the user and then I'll use that image. I saw a lot of ways like PyQt and OpenCV but they require such additional libraries. I though of using cheese using the os.system() command and hence the question. I hope it's clear now. @JacobVlijm

Comment: Much better! Maybe edit the question accordingly. I'd suggest not using os.system though, very, very old fashioned and deprecated.

Comment: btw, "feed it to my trained neural network and get some response" is done from cli? if so, by what command?